# patching slightly different files on common stuff

Tags: windows, unix, osx-leopard

I have tried using regular diff and patch to do what follows, but it 
doesn't seem to work or I am not using it right.  I am wondering if there 
is a tool to patch changes to a file based on the actual line content.
For example, I have the following similar files with common lines but 
different line orderings:

```
  File 1.txt
  Hi, my name is Ted.
  1
  2
  3
  4

  File 2.txt
  1
  2
  3
  4
  Hi, my name is Ted


  File 3.txt
  1
  2
  Hi, my name is Ted
  3
  4


  I change File 1.txt to:
  Hi, my name is Joe.
  1
  2
  3
  40
```

and now I want to create some sort of patch or distribute this change to the other files, but not by coping the entire contents of File 1.txt to the other files, but by chaning only common lines:

```
  4
```

to

```
  40
```

and

```
  Hi, my name is Ted.
```

to

```
  Hi, my name is Joe.
```

Any help appreciated,

Ted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Different OSes may have totally different tools*

## Sed (exist on *nix, ported to Win, know nothing abt OSX)

From example

```
 # substitute (find and replace) "foo" with "bar" on each line

 sed 's/foo/bar/'             # replaces only 1st instance in a line
```

i.e. smth. like

```
sed 's/4/40/' 2.txt > 2e.txt
...
sed 's/4/40/' 4.txt > 4e.txt
```

or

```
sed 's/4/40/' 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt> common.txt
```

and split merged common.txt after

## diff (see above)

Prepare two intermediate-edited versions of 1.txt

1a will be

```
  Hi, my name is Joe.
  1
  2
  3
  4
```

1b will be

```
  Hi, my name is Ted.
  1
  2
  3
  40
```

Prepare patches

```
diff -U 0 1.txt 1a.txt > fix1.patch

diff -U 0 1.txt 1b.txt > fix2.patch
```

Apply patches

```
patch -u -b 2.txt fix1.patch
...
patch -u -b 3.txt fix2.patch
```

Results of commands from head was not tested

## awk script (see above)

## [GrepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html) (Windows only)

Write search-replace pattern (regexps supported), test, store in presets